# Still and yet together in the same sentence ,does it make sense?

Tags: sentence-construction

> I **still** have not received it **yet**.

Does it make sense?

If so is "still" use to emphasise that the event has not happened yet and may won't happen?

Comment: `“I still have not received it yet does it make sense?”` does ***not*** make any sense. Please use proper punctuation.

Comment: It should be `“I still have not received it yet” Does it make sense?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I **still** have not received it.

**Please  note**: I still received it. [means anyway: I received it anyway]

- still is not used in the interrogative when it means yet.
- I still have not received it.= I have not received it yet. Same thing.

**Use one or the other**, not both. Take note of the position of the adverb.

Please note: Have you received it yet? They haven't received it yet.